# Responsive control panel styles

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, user-interface

I have a plugin that extends various Craft templates and styles, however, in one area it requires some custom Control Panel styles that Craft has not already created. As the Craft Control Panel is responsive, I'd like the UI elements I'm creating to also be responsive.

It appears Craft makes it's UI components responsive using a combination of @media queries and javascript.

What is the best way for me to build out a custom plugin UI that is consistent with the breakpoints that Craft is using and will be least likely to break if Craft updates anything down the road?

Comment: Craft CMS on GitHub appears to use SCSS; could you perhaps pull that down locally, and use that as a dev dependency in your build system, using whatever breakpoint variables it may already have set? I know it doesn't address the JS issues, but it's a start...